# findviewbyid returning null when trying to find NumberPicker in other fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, findviewbyid, numberpicker

My code is huge on this project, so I will try and summarize what is happening to the best of my knowledge.  I have looked through forums and tried multiple routes at fixing this issue.  I'm hoping it's something obvious that I'm missing.

I used the `tablayout` project that android studio creates during the new project wizard, 4 tabs (made each tab have it's own fragment).

On fragment 1 I have the `onclicklistener` trying to change the value of a `numberpicker` on fragment 2.  My problem is that my `findviewbyid` on the `numberpicker` keeps coming back null.  I have tried multiple formats for the `findviewbyid` and it keeps returning null.

Basically I'm trying to access an object on another fragment and `findviewbyid` isn't finding that object.

```
otherpck = (NumberPicker) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pckOther);
otherpck.setValue(5);
```

If I run the above code in the `onclicklistener` for a button on fragment 1 trying to find `pckOther` on fragment 2 it sets `otherpck` to null.

All fragments have been inflated.  I can click on all the tabs, then the button on fragment1 and still get null.

Thanks in advance for an help given.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to access another Fragment's view directly, in general, communication between Fragments should be done through the Activity.

Comment: What about inflating the second fragment layout and accessing that picker through the inflated layout (view)? But you shouldn't need to do this, read @Egor comment

Comment: @Egor - so I would call a method in mainactivity to modify fragment 2? I tried that and got the same issue

Comment: @dolphinziyo - if I inflate a fragment after it's already inflated, won't that create another fragment? all of the tabs/fragments have already been inflated. Thanks to both of you for the quick replies

Comment: Why don't you use intents and pass the data as extra ?

Comment: @yasin - my question is, if I have already inflated the activities, why can't I just reference objects between fragments with findbyid?  I will look into intents also.

Comment: @will because android manages your activity and pauses/stops them on demand. So imagine you are in activity B and you go for lunch and you come back 30 mins later your Activity B will be resumed but there is a very big chance android killed your activity A so when you try to access it's view it will return null.

Comment: @yasin - ah, that makes more sense then.  I'm guessing that the answer is no, but is there anyway to mark an activity 'unkillable' so that android won't kill it?  thank you for your quick replies.

Comment: You got it. There is no way. Even if it was fully possible, you shouldn't build apps that would remain open in the background and consume memory infinitely.

Comment: @yasin - I just threw a log write in my oncreate of the other activity and when I would click on two diff tabs then back to the previous third, the oncreate would fire.  Not what I thought was happening.  Thanks.  How can I upvote your 'solution' to my question?  I don't see a way.

Comment: Glad i could help. I will post it as an answer and you can select it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly access a fragment's view from another activity/fragment because android manages your activity and pauses/stops them on demand. So imagine you are in activity B and you go for lunch and you come back 30 mins later your Activity B will be resumed but there is a very big chance android killed your activity A so when you try to access it's view it will return null.

Instead you can use one of these options.

Use Bundle. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

1) Use the Bundle from the Intent:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the putExtra() shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

Then, in the launched Activity, you would read them via:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
```

This is the proper way to do that. Another way is SharedPreferences. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

There is slightly issue you cannot ask for view if its not created and attached to activity. as you said you are using fragments, if that fragment is not attached to your activity yet, your activity don't have access to that view.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the issue has already been solved.  Also, I stated before that all of the fragments had already been inflated:

"All fragments have been inflated. I can click on all the tabs, then the button on fragment1 and still get null."

It's not that they hadn't been inflated "yet", but that android had closed them down after they were inflated.

Answer (score 0):

replace this lines:

```
otherpck = (NumberPicker) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pckOther);
```

by this lines:

```
otherpck = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pckOther);
```